# which CSS query method is the best to use:container query.element query or media query?

Tags: wordpress

I like to know which kind of queries  I have to use because  this is my first website I am developing and I am working with foundation grid system.
I see at this moment you have containers queries  which is more targeted to an element .  also I see you have  element queries and media queries.
to have modern responsive website which one I have to use and why?
container query,element query or media query?
what is your advise to me?
thanks
johan

Answer (score -1):

The concept of Container Queries is rather new and enables adjusting Elements to the Container, Not Viewport. Container queries would grant you more control over styling in contrast to Media queries but Media queries are largely supported. To use container queries you will need to add extensions. It depends upon how much control does your site require on the responsiveness of its elements.

Do you want to control each and every element of your site individually?
Use container queries.

Otherwise go for traditional media queries.

[Read here](https://alistapart.com/article/container-queries-once-more-unto-the-breach) for a more extensive discussion on this.